# RocksDB: too many comparisons when using custom comparator

Tags: comparison, rocksdb

I am using RocksDB for storing and indexing encrypted data of fixed size of about 3KB (key,value = encryted_data, insertion_sequence_number), and for that purpose I'm providing a custom comparator to be used by RocksDB when inserting and searching. It compares the keys by decrypting them, so it is time consuming. This works well, but I noticed that the number of comparisons is much bigger than what I would expect for a given number of values. I also noticed that the number of stored values is bigger than what I expected.

Here is an example: I insert the values 1,2,3,7,14,22. (Each value is encrypted on insertion). When I print all contents I have:

RocksDB contents:

```
[row000]<[00007f1ebc0079d00d0000000000000068cd01bc1e7f0000]> -> {}

[row001]<[00007f1ebc0019900d0000000000000068cd01bc1e7f0000]> -> {}

[row002]<[c750e38063a871001af286720d7943095111a0dba808d00d]> -> {00000000}

[row003]<[f146398078a31c00de0aa3026f855101c36592eae1324905]> -> {01000000}

[row004]<[d687a251eb43d1081bb2ebaf0dd9f5077029f213b814f909]> -> {02000000}

[row005]<[571050962b08280b9f5b1ca9cf2d8e04959cd6d14a4eeb08]> -> {03000000}

[row006]<[4d4f01d6a6a7000b8800af4b4480d705bd9987efdeccc307]> -> {04000000}

[row007]<[5ee699152ff3cc0a21e3e8da9071740d7559b1b5baacd80a]> -> {05000000}

[row008]<[00007f1ebc0525000d0000000000000068cd01bc1e7f0000]> -> {}

[row009]<[00007f1ebc02ef500d0000000000000068cd01bc1e7f0000]> -> {}

[row010]<[00007f1ebc0191f00d0000000000000068cd01bc1e7f0000]> -> {}
```

Instead of 6, I have 11, so 5 are not coming from me. The number of comparisons for the last insertion is above 100. If I make a search, my comparator function is called above 100 times too. The values compared are mine and not mine, which doesn't make any sens because not valid encrypted values can not have a valid decryption.

What could explain such behavior? Fake values are maybe leaves of a tree internally used for storage, but the huge number of comparisons?